# Passing Variables Into URL

Tags: jquery

I am trying to ad the values from 2 form elements into a function and can get the first to add but can't work out the correct way to code for the second.

```
$(function() {
   $('#form_orderTracking').click(function(){
       $('#CustomerDetails').load('TrackOrder1.asp?OrderID=' + $('#orderID').val());
   });
});
```

I am trying to add the value for the emailAddress field so that the url reads:

```
TrackOrder1?OrderID=123456&EmailAddress=abc@123.com
```

Comment: `'TrackOrder1.asp?OrderID=' + $('#orderID').val() + '&EmailAddress=' + email`?

Comment: @Darren Cook You are just adding orderid, do what Rocket said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending the query string to the url, you can pass it to `.load` as a 2nd parameter.  If you pass an object, it'll use `POST`, if you pass a string, it'll use `GET` (like your example).

`$.param` converts the object to a string, so it uses `GET`.

```
$('#CustomerDetails').load('TrackOrder1.asp', $.param({
    orderID: $('#orderID').val(),
    EmailAddress: emailAddress
}));
```

Or you can just append to your string, like so:

```
$('#CustomerDetails').load('TrackOrder1.asp?OrderID=' + $('#orderID').val() + '&EmailAddress=' + emailAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'TrackOrder1.asp?OrderID=' + uriEncodeComponent($('#orderID').val()) + '&EmailAddress=' + uriEncodeComponent(email);
$('#CustomerDetails').load(url);
```

It is also best to run the values through `uriEncodeComponent()` to ensure they are encoded properly.